# Prove that the series converges using the alternating series test, and find the value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\frac{(-1)^{k+1}k}{3^k}$$

Correct me if I am wrong but with $(-1)^{k+1}$ this makes it an alternating series test therefore i think I need to show that $\frac{k}{3^k}$ is decreasing and non-negative. But the problem with that is that there is no restriction on bounds. So maybe Direcheltes test would be more appropriate and let $a_k=(-1)^{k+1}$ which is bounded I believe and let $b_k = \frac{k}{3^k}$ and show that it is approaching 0 by taking the limit as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

1)$a_k= \dfrac{k}{3^k} >0$ is decreasing.

$\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\dfrac{(k+1)3^k}{k3^{k+1}}=$

$(1/3)\dfrac{k+1}{k} =(1/3)(1+1/k) <1$ for $k=1,2,3....$

2)$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}a_k=0$.

3) Leibniz alternating series test.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $k/3^{k}\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Now by elementary calculus applied to the derivative of $x/3^{x}$ for $x>0$, we conclude that $k/3^{k}$ is decreasing for $k$ large, then Alternating Series Test does the job completely.

Comment: could you set it up?

Comment: Which part? Set up what?

Comment: the alternating series test

Comment: Well, another user just provided the details.

Comment: yes I see that now. Was there an issue with the title?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but somehow your title is some sort of "commanding people" to complete your work, which is not allowed, I think.

Comment: okay that makes sense